# Postgres Query Optimization-Update Query

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, query-optimization

I have below two queries which takes time when there is lot of records in DB like 2000000.The column value in 'Where' clause of both queries are dynamic. Can anyone suggest me to to optimize these in a better way?

```
UPDATE demo.document_details
SET has_dc = 'Y', l3_validation = 'Y',
    validation_remark = CONCAT(validation_remark,
                               'Deliverychallan also available against this document (Alert)<br>'),
    fu_5 = CASE WHEN fu_5 = 'Success'
                THEN 'Alert'
                ELSE fu_5
           END
WHERE document_no = '123'
  AND document_date = '2018-09-05'
  AND user_gstin = 'gstinid'
  AND document_type != 'DELIVERY CHALLAN'
  AND has_dc IS NULL;

UPDATE demo.document_details
SET is_exclude = 'Y',
    l3_validation = 'Y',
    validation_remark = CONCAT(validation_remark,
                               'Cancelled document (Alert)<br>'),
    exclude_reason = 'Cancelled document',
    fu_5 = CASE WHEN fu_5 = 'Success'
                THEN 'Alert'
                ELSE fu_5
           END
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: The best you can do is to create an index for the `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: I already created index but still it takes time for large no. of records in DB.

Comment: Updating a lot of rows is going to take time, no matter what.